# Booking an 'invalid' appointment in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need to add some appointments from a legacy system into Dynamics. During the transition, the team involved has changed some details of their available working hours to take advantage of CRM's more flexible scheduling system.

Of course, they don't want to amend the time of existing appointments with customers just because the internal processes have changed.

If you enter an appointment manually on the calendar, it will allow you to "Ignore and save" scheduling conflicts, but I have several hundred appointments to book: is there a way to book appointments that aren't 'valid' via the webservices? At the moment, it will only book the appointments would be valid under the new scheduling rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the WSDL from the CrmService, you can create appointments like this:

```
CrmService service = new CrmService();

// service connection configuration goes here

appointment appt = new appointment();
appt.ownerid = new Owner() { Value = systemUserIdForApptOwner };
appt.scheduledstart = new CrmDateTime() { Value = dateTimeStartString };
appt.scheduledend = new CrmDateTime() { Value = dateTimeEndString };
appt.subject = subjectOfAppt;

service.Create(appt);
```

Using the web service to create appointments, you are allowed to create conflicting appointments.  It's the responsibility of the developer to handle that situation.

Comment: Headslap moment... All this time I've been trying to 'Book' the appointment. It never occurred to me to just 'create' it!